# How to output multiple strings to the screen at the same time with pthreads or curses in C++

Tags: c++, string, position

I compile my app on DEV C++ and I use the pthreads library to multi-thread. 
My main thread consists of printing "Hello World" to the start of the screen (0,0).
My newly created thread consists of printing "Monday" to the middle of the screen, top row (0,60). Since I am using pthreads, they execute at the same time which is good. But, since there is only 1 cursor, it could only print one at a time. I want them both to be printed at the exact moment they execute. I write to the screen with simple cout << "Hello World";

Would I need some type of curses library to write multiple strings at the exact time they execute? Or could I do it through standard C++? Remember, I want to output 2 things, and it outputs one at a time. How do I output 2 strings at the same time, at different coordinates?

Comment: Run all your curses commands out of a single thread. Get your other threads to queue work to the curses thread.

Comment: Because of the single current cursor position, you must treat `curses` as single-threaded.  Ensure that only one thread is actively using `curses` at any given time.  (If you have separate sub-windows, then separate threads could probably update the separate sub-windows concurrently.  However, the `refresh()` must be single-threaded, and care is still required.  Input must be single-threaded. It is simplest to assume single-threading.)  Also, note that if you're using curses, you should not write to the screen with `cout << "Hello World"`; you should be using `curses` primitives to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Like David H says in the comment, use one thread to write to the display, and have a queue.

The queue might contain some data like this:

```
class printing
{
 public:
   printing(int x, int y, const std::string &str);

 private:
   const std::string m_str;
   int m_x;
   int m_y;
};

std::queue<printing> print_queue;
```

You will need a mutex or similar to add/remove things to the queue.

```
std::mutex print_queue_mutex;

void add_printing(printing &pr)
{
    print_queue_mutex.lock();
    print_queue.push_back(pr);
    print_queue_mutex.unlock();
}
```

I'll let you figure out how to do the actual "print from queue" functionality. It follow the same principle.

Answer (score 0):

create a lock that the threads have to acquire before they write to the screen.